# how to hide the parameter value in href in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp

here is my problem. How could I hide the value of the parameter from the url? because I don't have idea how to hide it. it keep on appearing like this (http://localhost:8084/YIP/MentorServlet?action=peribadi&mentorid=951218-02-5598)

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;
</a>
  <% String id=request.getParameter("mentorid");%>
  <li>
      <a href="MentorView.jsp">Utama</a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a href="MentorServlet?action=peribadi&mentorid=<%=id%>">Peribadi</a>
  </li>
```

Comment: If you reffer to the parameter not showing in the url you have to send it in the body using POST method instead of GET method. To do it in html, use a form and send the value as a input type hidden.

Comment: define "hide" Should it be just not present in the url, or do you want the user to not be able to access it?

Comment: just not present in the url

Comment: does the link in the anchor bother you, or the link what the user sees _after_ arriving to the next page? (btw+fyi: the question is HTML as the JSP code does not exist on the client side)

Comment: the link after arriving to the next page because I think it is not secure to have the value. Thank you for correcting me about the JSP btw :)

Answer (score 1):

Some options:

- do nothing: this is the best one, as there is no such thing as securely hiding something in HTML. Whoever looks into the page source, will see how the servlet in question can be invoked
- switch to a form and a submit button, something what @alayor shows. If you use POST, the parameters will not appear in the URL
- switch to a form, but keep the looks of an anchor and submit form from JavaScript ([some docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) [some overcomplicated examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript))
- manipulate browser history from the target page ([docs1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/History), [docs2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API))
- keep mentorid in a session variable on server-side: hackers never see it
- keep mentorid in an encrypted cookie: hackers see it, but can not decode. However they can try reusing it later ([replay attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack))
- the various other ones I have forgotten and/or never even heard about

Answer (score 0):

You can create an HTML for instead of an anchor.

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;
</a>
  <% String id=request.getParameter("mentorid");%>
  <li>
      <a href="MentorView.jsp">Utama</a>
  </li>
  <li>
     <form action="/MentorServlet" method="POST">
       <input type="hidden" name="action" value="peribadi" />
       <input type="hidden" name="mentorid" value="<%=id%>" />
       <button>Peribadi</button>
     </form>
  </li>
```

This way you can avoid sending the parameter in the URL and it will send in the HTTP Request Body instead.